# ethereum No geth.ipc in the folder

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

ethereum  No geth.ipc in the folder

Terminal display

````
PS C:\Users\88693\Desktop\rian\dada1> ls
目錄: C:\Users\88693\Desktop\rian\dada1


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2020/9/8  下午 03:08                geth
d-----       2020/9/8  下午 03:08                keystore


PS C:\Users\88693\Desktop\rian\dada1> geth attach ipc:/geth.ipc
Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: Invalid pipe address '/geth.ipc'.```
````

Answer (score 0):

The geth.ipc file will not be created, if there is any error in starting the ethereum nodes.(after executing ./startnode1.sh)  Please check your log file to find the error.